# Remove a word from the List by ignoring case sensitive

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to delete all occurrences of a word in the `ArrayList` from a given string .

I have 3 buttons on my frame. One that adds words, a second that removes words, and the third that shows words.

I have a textbox with name `textvalue` and array list with name `mylist`

I used:

```
 textValue = text.getText().toLowerCase().trim();
 if (mylist.contains(textValue)) { 
                  mylist.removeAll(Arrays.asList(textValue)); 
                 label.setText("All occurrences of " + textValue + "removed");
                        } else {
                            label.setText("Word not found.");
                        }
```

If I put for example : mark and MARK , it will still only delete mark.

I have also tried:

```
textValue = text.getText().toLowerCase().trim();
                            for (String current : mylist) {
                                if (current.equalsIgnoreCase(textValue)) {
                                    mylist.removeAll(Collections.singleton(textValue));
                                    label.setText("All occurrences of " + textValue + " removed");
                                } else {
                                    label.setText("Word not found.");
                                }

                            }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use [removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
mylist.removeIf(value->value.equalsIgnoreCase(textValue));
```

`removeIf` accepts [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) as an argument, So you are defining corresponding [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to delete all values that matches to `textValue` by ignoring case sensitive

Comment: @Javazzs look into lambda expressions

Comment: The part `value -> value.equalsIgnoreCase(textValue)` takes every single element from the list (named `value` here) and removes it if `value.equalsIgnoreCase(textValue)` is `true`. **Works in Java 8 and higher.**

Answer (score 1):

@Deadpool's solution using `removeIf()` is simplest, but I thought I'd also suggest a stream solution.  This is a little more verbose, but has the advantage that, since you're creating a new `List`, this will work even if the original `List` is immutable.

```
mylist = mylist.stream().filter(s -> !s.equalsIgnoreCase(textValue)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Basically what you're doing here is streaming the original `List`, returning each element that matches the `Predicate`, and then collecting them into a new `List`.

You'll notice that you need to negate the equals check, in order to return only those elements that *don't* match `textValue`.